# Forecasting with a gap of negative 1

Tags: h2o, forecasting, driverless-ai

I am using H2O.ai to understand both current week and lagged week features that affect the target value of the current week.
Using the Walmart example.

For a particular week of sales, I am interested in the features that most likely affect how well or poorly sales performed. 
To set this problem up, I want H2O.ai to 'predict' what the current week of sales are using the current week feature values as well as the lagged values (including the lag of the target) -- i.e., this is not a forecast problem, but a problem to understand the drivers.

In forecasting terms, this would be setting the prediction horizon to 1 and the gap of negative 1.

However, H2O.ai seems to not allow you to set it in this unconventional way.

How would I set up this experiment in H2O.ai?

Answer (score 0):

The problem described corresponds to a multi-variate time series problem that uses only lags 0 and 1. Of course, it can't and won't use use lag 0 on target, but it can will use lag 0 on other time series and features.

To setup the problem in Driverless AI properly with walmart dataset set:

- **target column**: `Weekly_Sales`
- **time column**: `Date`
- **time group columns** (TGC): `Store`, `Dept`
- **Forecast horizon**: 1 week
- **Gap**: 0 week
- *Expert Settings -> Time Series*:

  - **Time Series Lag Override**: 1
  - (optional but recommended) **Probability to create non-target lag features**: 0.5 or higher
  - (optional but worth trying) **Always Group by All Time Groups Columns for Creating Lag Features**: Disabled

With lag override set to 1 no lags greater than 1 can be used to predict target, plus current (lag 0) features (everything but target). So, effectively, it still a forecast problem but it complies with all restrictions you placed in your question.